# How to create a session variable in php using phpsessionmanager class

Tags: session, session-variables, php

I found a PHP class

> [PHPsessionManager](https://code.google.com/p/phpsessionmanager/)

*The article that talks about it can be found [How to create a bulletproof-sessions](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-create-bulletproof-sessions)*

This class is about creating a secured session where the `session_id` changes with every request and the also request is destroyed so an attacker won't be able to find any session.

The instructions states, in order to create a new session then you do:

```
// Creates a basic session.
SessionManager::sessionStart('InstallationName');
```

But how can I set a session variable? (ie. `$_SESSION['first_name'] = 'Mike';` )

So how can I save different variables in this session?

Comment: Looking at the code in `PHPSessionManager`, it appears that you can do just what you have in your question - `$_SESSION['first_name'] = 'Mike'`. Did you try it?

Comment: I tried it but it is not working.

Comment: How is it not working? The data that you read out is not the data that you set in the `$_SESSION` array?

Comment: correct. when I do echo $_SESSION['first_name'] nothing is printed.

Comment: When are you setting the variable in `$_SESSION`? If you do it before you run `SessionManager::sessionStart('InstallationName')` then it will get wiped out.

Answer (score 1):

When I take a look at the class itself, (http://phpsessionmanager.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Session.class.php) I think that this class isn't being used to initiate a session variable as you want to use it.

For example: You can initialize this class AFTER a user logged in on your site. This way, you can identify the user (afterwards) without the need for requesting the user credentials again.

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I think so. But should it be also to secure the session variables?

Comment: No, instead of using a regular session, this class creates a cookie. So you don't use this for variables. Just te keep track of a user that has been logged in. (So that the user doesn't have to enter his credentials every time)

Comment: so I would only use this class to check if the user is logged in and nothing else? if this is the case then how would I use session variables securely?

Comment: Depending on the information you want to store in the session and what you want to use it for, can you hash it. And I you really want everything to be safe, you can use SSL.
Also, session variables are server side, so the user can't see or manipulate it. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430253/view-and-change-sessions-variables-in-a-browser)

Comment: I see. So how can evaluate if this use is authorized? first I would match the user_name/password in the database. if I can match them then i will start the session SessionManager::sessionStart('InstallationName'). But how would I check if the session is authorized?

Comment: You initiate the session after the user has authenticated.
This class doesn't create a session based on username or password, instead it uses the user agent and IP-address. So the class checks if the session is still valid. I'm not sure if I answered your question.

Comment: would it be possible to move to the chat? I just need clarification.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51701/discussion-between-dieter-kempeneers-and-mike)